# Matrix derivatives from Lecture 4 of CS231n

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation

I've been going through CS231n material. I am confused with this matrix derivation.

Here in this image the derivation of df/dx is given. Its from lecture 4 slide 73. [image: lecture 4 slides]

I understand this way of solving the derivative. But when I try to solve it using the chain rule directly I get a different answer. Here is how I worked out my solution. I know this has to be wrong, but I could not figure out where I'm wrong. Please let me know whats wrong this.

[image: my derivation]

Sorry for the images. I dont know how to do latex.

Comment: check [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1887688/help-me-to-derive-the-derivative-for-ax-btax-b)

Answer (score 1):

The mistake you made was in using the wrong form of the chain rule. In univariate calculus, it does not matter if you write $\frac{d}{dx} f(g(x)) = f'(g(x)) g'(x)$ or if you write $\frac{d}{dx} f(g(x)) = g'(x) f'(g(x))$.

However, since matrix multiplcation is not commutative, you do need to be careful about the order when dealing with matrix calculus.

When treating the gradient as a column vector (denominator layout), which is the case in this problem, the chain rule is: $$\frac{d}{dx} f(g(x)) = g'(x) f'(g(x))$$

When treating the gradient as a row vector (numerator layout), the chain rule is:
$$\frac{d}{dx} f(g(x)) = f'(g(x)) g'(x)$$

For this case we want the first version, so $\frac{\partial q}{\partial x}$ goes in front of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial q}$ which gives you the answer: $2W^T q$.

The slide you posted got the right answer without paying attention to the order of the two terms was because they did the derivative element-wise, without matrices, which means this issue doesn't appear.

Source: last row of [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Vector-by-vector_identities)

Comment: This is not correct.  The notation "$f(g(x))$" refers to the composition of functions $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^1$ and $f:\mathbb{R}^1\to\mathbb{R}^1$. By definition, their derivatives are linear transformations $Dg:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^1$ and $Df:\mathbb{R}^1\to\mathbb{R}^1$ (which is represented by *number*, by the way). For $n\ne 1$ the only meaningful way to combine these derivatives is to compose $Df$ with $Dg$.  When vectors are written as columns, as in the question, this results in the matrix multiplication $Df\cdot Dg$.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by $f(g(x))$ meaning that $g$ maps $R^n$ to $R^1$ and $f$ maps $R^1$ to $R^1$. Is this related to the fact that I overloaded $f$ in the question with a different use?

Comment: Perhaps we interpret $f$ and $g$ differently.  I have understood your $f$ to be $f(y)=y^2$ and your $g$ to be $g(x)=w^\prime x$. If we take $W$ to be an $m\times n$ matrix rather than a vector, then $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ and $f:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^1$ is given by $f(y)=||y||^2$. This makes $Dg$ an $m\times n$ matrix and $Df$ is a $1\times m$ matrix. Indeed, $Df(q)=2q^\prime$ and $Dg(y)=W$, whence $D(g(f(x))=2q^\prime W$. If we instead write vectors as rows--which clearly is *not* the case in the question--then we would obtain $2W^\prime q$.

Comment: Yes, I was using the matrix interpretation of W. I would contest the claim that $Dg$ is $m$ by $n$ and $Df$ is $1$ by $m$. The OP of the question wrote $\frac{d}{dx} Ax = A^T$ and $\frac{d}{dq}{||q||^2} = 2q$, which indicates they were using denominator layout convention, so the derivative of a function from $R^m$ to $R^n$ would be $m$ by $n$.

Comment: Right--and therein lies the difficulty.  A close reading of the question--including the first graphic--shows that vectors are column vectors.  Thus, the problem is the OP's inconsistency in quoting the Chain Rule as if vectors were row vectors.  As it stands, although your answer is not incorrect, it still obscures that fundamental issue.

Comment: I see what you mean. I thought it might be more likely that the OP was unaware of the importance of the ordering of the terms in the chain rule, versus the possibility that they were aware of the row form of the chain rule and the column form of it, and used the wrong one. I will try to rewrite the answer with what you said in mind.

Comment: Thank you--those small changes have helped quite a lot.  I especially appreciate your attention to accompanying your analysis with explanations and careful reasons (+1).